# IntelliJ 404 scala lang

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Ok, I need some help in setting up a Scala project with IntelliJ, I have download and installed the project successfully, but i have had issues when it comes to installing the Scala compiler itself, WHen i go to configure a new Scalaa project and choose to set the Scala home, I choose the download Scala option and i get the following error "downloading failed, connection failed with error 404: http://www.scala.lang.org/downloads.distrib/files/scala2.10.0+RC2.tgz" i have tried downloading the things, such as primefaces and jSF through intelij, and they all work fine, any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging what seems to be a connection error between specific client-software and it's managing domain.

Answer (score 1):

Download Scala manually and just select proper directory in new project window.

http://www.scala-lang.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using SBT to define and build your project. Among other things, it handles retrieving the Scala compiler and libraries. IDEA is similarly self-contained as far as its Scala plug-in's internal Scala compiler is concerned. By using SBT and IDEA (see below for connecting the two), the only thing not covered is a Scala REPL for use outside of either SBT or IDEA. If you're using a Mac, [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) includes a Scala formula. Because SBT retrieves the Scala compiler and libraries for the version of Scala you specified, everything is self-contained.

By far the best way to build and maintain IDEA project definitions for Scala projects is with the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plug-in for SBT. Once you install that plug-in, which is trivial, you simply use the `gen-idea` SBT task it provides. When your dependencies change, you run `gen-idea` again to update the project.